# Building a new array using key IDS

Tags: php, arrays

Using the numbers from `$ids`, I want to pull the data from `$nuts`.

So for example:

```
$ids = [0,3,5]; // 0 calories, 3 sugar, 5 fat

$nuts = [
    'calories' => 'cal',
    'protein' => 'pro',
    'carbohydrate' => 'car',
    'sugar' => 'sug',
    'fiber' => 'fib',
    'fat' => 'fat',
];

$returnData = [
    'calories' => 'cal',
    'sugar' => 'sug',
    'fat' => 'fat',
];
```

I could loop through each `$ids` number with a `foreach();` but I'm curious to see if there is a better method than this?

```
$newNuts = array_values(array_flip($nuts));
foreach($ids as $i)
    $returnData[$newNuts[$i]] = $nuts[$newNuts[$i]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)?

```
$result = array();
foreach ($ids as $i) {
    $result += array_slice($nuts, $i, 1, true);
}
```

No need to create a copy of the array.

Answer (score 2):

I did some work and realized, you don't need `array_flip`, `array_values` is fine.

```
$num_nuts = array_values ($nuts);

for ($z=0; $z<sizeof($ids); $z++) {
 echo $num_nuts[$ids[$z]];            
 }
```

Just 1 more line of code, but I think it does the job. I think mine is going to be faster because the `array_flip` basically exchanges all keys with their associated values in an array, which is not what I am doing. It's actually one less pain.

I am simply converting the original array to a new one by index and simply looping upon it. Also, not the elegant way to use the power of PHP available to us, but works just fine. `array_flip is O(n)`, but I think better not use it for larger data-sets.